# Border in Detail band

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a question about how border should display in detail band, and I would like to get some help.

Say, a column in detail band that might have LOTS data, by lots, I meant sometimes a single record might actually took 2~3 page to display.

Now customer ask that we should make report always display bottom line of the border as long as it meets end of page (even this record its not end yet)

What I tried:

- Make a column footer with 1px height line. 
  Set "Floating column footer" to TRUE.

  Result : It works great, but this line will make extra empty space at end of the table if there is a Summary band after the column footer. I think I am close, but I just can't get rid of the strange empty space
- Make a Frame with border, set "Print when detail overflow" to TRUE then put everything in detail band into this frame.

  Result : Not work as I expected :(

Since this report contains not just a table in detail band, and the height of the table are random. Tricks like a border in Background or Page Footer are not suitable here

What else can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `PrintWhenExpression` trick that can help with the page footer:

[How to hide Page X / Y when report is 1 page ? - JasperForge Forum](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=46357#46370)

The trick is to put a flag in the Report Parameter Map, then use the flag to decide whether text (or fields, lines, etc.) should be printed.

To use a line in Page Footer there will always be some pages with extra line. In this case, the report is always starting from page 1, and the table in the report always end before printing the Summary band. That means, the line is no longer necessary as long as Summary band has been reached. Thus:

- Add a line in Page Footer with PrintWhenExpression :

  > new Boolean(!(Boolean.TRUE).equals($P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("stopFlag")))
- Then make a dummy textField in Summary band with PrintWhenExpression like this :

  > $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("stopFlag",Boolean.TRUE)

This trick works, but might need some tweaking for different layouts.

Answer (score 2):

The option given by Dave is right.

If you care about the space still being used, then set the band and textfield heights to zero.

In my case using Dave's option worked (and I needed no extra space to be used).

I put this as `PrintWhenExpression` in the fields I just wanted to show in the last page:

```
$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("lastPage")!=null
```

And this as `PrintWhenExpression` in a 0-height textfield in the 0-heigth summary band:

```
$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.put("lastPage",":)")
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to page termination the options are limited.  Its made even hard because if you have items that do not display when null it still assumes that space is used.

I would stick with messing around with the column footer or page footer as your best options.